# Is this a simple example of an embedding?

Tags: geometry

Say I have a plane described by a two vectors $\vec{v}_1 = \langle1,1,1,1,1 \rangle$ and $\vec{v}_2 = \langle8,1,5,3,2 \rangle$.  Is it correct to say that this plane is an embedding of $\mathbb{R}^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^5$?

Comment: Yes, it is correct to say that.

Comment: Great, thanks.  Put it as an answer and I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct to say that that plane is an embedding of ${\bf R}^2$ in ${\bf R}^5$.